# Pandas dataframe map rows values with column names

Tags: python, pandas

My row values are
`[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]`, and column_names `['col1','col2','col3','col4','col5','col6','col7']`

How do I make a single dataframe for pandas, like this:

```
col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7
  1   2    3     4    5    6   7
```

Answer (score 4):

Use nested list:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]],
                      columns=['col1','col2','col3','col4','col5','col6','col7'])
print (new_df)
   col1  col2  col3  col4  col5  col6  col7
0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7
```

Comment: I don't think the op meant creating a new df, but rather filtering it. I might be wrong, but i'll write an separate awnser for it

Comment: @Felício Actually he meant new Df.

Comment: @arshpreet jezrael awnser should work in that case. Anyway, I'll leave it in case it's useful for someone else.

Answer (score 0):

If you meant filtering an existing df you could do It in many ways, here is my suggestion:

```
#first you create the auxiliary lists
values = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
cols = ['col1','col2','col3','col4','col5','col6','col7']

#next, you create a filter for each column
bool_filter = None
for col, value in zip(cols, values):
   if is None bool_filter:
       bool_filter = df[col] == value
   else:
       bool_filter = bool_filter & (df[col] == value)

#finnaly apply it to the df
df[bool_filter]
```

Comment: To create a new_df from this filter he could assign it at the end with `new_df = df[bool_filter]`